# Track user daily login function Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a quick question. I am writing a function that determines whether a user is logged in for the day as part of a larger effort to track daily logins and user that function in the controller to increment (or not) a point value per user. I know that the Devise gem has the Trackable module to record such values for the user. But when using those methods in an overall function, would I need to keep track of the last sign in time and compare that to the current sign in time. Kinda of confused on how to implement this in a user login tracking function. Would anyone be able to help?

Comment: Seems like you looking for another gem for your project if yes please check this one https://github.com/ankane/authtrail

Answer (score 1):

I think you can go at this multiple ways if you want to roll it yourself.

You can extend your user table with 2 columns (one for the current login and one for the previous login timestamp) and create an after login callback to update both columns.

You could create a second table (one user has many timestamps) and record every login timestamp for your users. Then you can compare the latest 2 logins

However, you have to consider that sessions get retained in cookies and a login depends largely on how long a cookie exists. Maybe what you want instead is when users request or update a resource that is gated behind the login?